# How do I filter multiple data frames in R?

Tags: r

> Im attempting to filter out every pitcher who doesnt meet the requirements in the filter. I get the error "Caused by error:
> ! object 'ff_avg_spin' not found"

> When i only attempted to filter one data frame, and assigned each frame a different name, it worked. I assigned both data frames the same name because I was desperate and couldnt figure out what to do.

```
library(baseballr)
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- statcast_leaderboards(
  leaderboard = "pitch_arsenal",
  year = 2021,
  abs = 50,
  min_pa = "q",
  min_pitches = "750",
  min_field = "q",
  min_run = 0,
  player_type = "pitcher",
  fielding_type = "player",
  oaa_position = "",
  oaa_roles = "",
  team = "",
  arsenal_type = 'avg_spin',
  run_type = 'percent',
  min2b = 0,
  min3b = 0,
  position = "",
  bats = "",
  hand = ""
)


df1 <- statcast_leaderboards(
leaderboard = "pitch_arsenal",
year = 2021,
abs = 50,
min_pa = "q",
min_pitches = "750",
min_field = "q",
min_run = 0,
player_type = "pitcher",
fielding_type = "player",
oaa_position = "",
oaa_roles = "",
team = "",
arsenal_type = 'avg_speed',
run_type = "percent",
min2b = 0,
min3b = 0,
position = "",
bats = "",
hand = ""
)


filter(df1,ff_avg_spin >= 2300 & 
cu_avg_spin >= 2650 & ff_avg_speed >= 
92.0 & cu_avg_speed > 80.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to filter on variables that are not present in your dataframe. You are saving both dataframes as `df1`, so you are just overwriting the first one you ran. So, you need to load both dataframes as different variables (`df1` and `df2`), then join the two together and finally use your filter statement.

```
library(tidyverse)

left_join(df1, df2, by = c("year", "last_name", "first_name", "pitcher")) %>% 
  filter(ff_avg_spin >= 2300 & 
         cu_avg_spin >= 2650 & ff_avg_speed >= 
         92.0 & cu_avg_speed > 80.0)
```

**Data**

```
library(baseballr)
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- statcast_leaderboards(
  leaderboard = "pitch_arsenal",
  year = 2021,
  abs = 50,
  min_pa = "q",
  min_pitches = "750",
  min_field = "q",
  min_run = 0,
  player_type = "pitcher",
  fielding_type = "player",
  oaa_position = "",
  oaa_roles = "",
  team = "",
  arsenal_type = 'avg_spin',
  run_type = 'percent',
  min2b = 0,
  min3b = 0,
  position = "",
  bats = "",
  hand = ""
)


df2 <- statcast_leaderboards(
leaderboard = "pitch_arsenal",
year = 2021,
abs = 50,
min_pa = "q",
min_pitches = "750",
min_field = "q",
min_run = 0,
player_type = "pitcher",
fielding_type = "player",
oaa_position = "",
oaa_roles = "",
team = "",
arsenal_type = 'avg_speed',
run_type = "percent",
min2b = 0,
min3b = 0,
position = "",
bats = "",
hand = ""
)
```

Comment: thank you. would there be any way to remove columns that are N/A?

Comment: @micah Yes, definitely. But do you want to remove columns that are only `NA` or a have a certain ratio of `NA`s or what?